# Is there a way to merge two JS objects with the same keys?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

if I have two objects:

```
{a: 1, b: {c: 1}}
```

and

```
{d: 1, b: {e: 2}}
```

Is there an easy way to merge the two nondestructively to create the following object?

```
{a: 1, d: 1, b: {c: 1, e: 2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Lodash. Here's the link to the method you need: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#merge